# Joomla Backend running slow on localhost

Tags: joomla, testing, xampp, localhost

I made a local backup of my Joomla site a few months ago to test changes before updating the live site. Everything worked fine.

Today I checked the local version after a while but when I open access the administration panel via `sitename.com/administrator` it takes a while until the site is loaded.

I tried out different things and accidentally disconnected my Network Connection. After that everything loads as fast as before. But when I connect the Network Connection the problem reappears.

I am running Joomla 1.5.14 on XAMPP 1.7.0.

Answer (score 1):

I would have to believe that something in your test Joomla site is attempting to call to your real site, whether it be through the front-end or back-end.